# Html to pdf some characters are missing (itextsharp) in Asp.Net MVC Application

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, pdf, utf-8, character-encoding, itext

I want to export razor view to pdf by using the itextsharp library. The problem is that some turkish characters such as İ,ı,Ş,ş etc... are missing in the pdf document. The code used to export the pdf is:

```
  public PdfActionResult(object model)
    {
        Model = model;
    }
 public override void ExecuteResult(ControllerContext context)
    {
        IView viewEngineResult;
        ViewContext viewContext;

        if (ViewName == null)
        {
            ViewName = context.RouteData.GetRequiredString("action");
        }

        context.Controller.ViewData.Model = Model;


        var workStream = new MemoryStream();
        var document = new Document();

        PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(document, workStream);
        writer.CloseStream = false;

        document.Open();

        viewEngineResult = ViewEngines.Engines.FindView(context, ViewName, null).View;
        var sb = new StringBuilder();
        TextWriter tr = new StringWriter(sb);

        viewContext = new ViewContext(context, viewEngineResult, context.Controller.ViewData,
        context.Controller.TempData, tr);
        viewEngineResult.Render(viewContext, tr);

        CultureInfo ci = new CultureInfo("az-Latn-AZ");
        Encoding enc = Encoding.GetEncoding(ci.TextInfo.ANSICodePage);

        Stream stream = new MemoryStream(enc.GetBytes(sb.ToString()));

        XMLWorkerHelper.GetInstance().ParseXHtml(writer, document, stream, null);

        document.Close();

        new FileContentResult(workStream.ToArray(), "application/pdf").ExecuteResult(context);
    }
}
```

Then I access it as:

```
 public ActionResult StudentPdf(Guid studentId)
    {
        var model = _studentRepository.GetByIdGuid(studentId);

        return new PdfActionResult(model);
    }
```

Thanks for reply

Comment: You're using XML Worker, but you're not providing a `FontProvider`. Hence you can only use Standard Type 1 fonts. These don't support Turkish characters. Introduce a `FontProvider` and provide fonts that know how to display special characters.

Comment: @Bruno, Could you explain this as an answer, please?

Comment: I usually don't answer questions marked "razor" because I don't think razor users use the latest version of iTextSharp and they usually aren't iText customers. However, this should point you in the right direction: http://itextpdf.com/sandbox/xmlworker/D06_ParseHtmlFonts More examples can be found on the official web site: http://itextpdf.com/sandbox/xmlworker

Answer (score 2, accepted):

by this way you can print all turkish character.

String htmlText = html.ToString();

```
        Document document = new Document();

        string filePath = HostingEnvironment.MapPath("~/Content/Pdf/");
        PdfWriter.GetInstance(document, new FileStream(filePath + "\\pdf-"+Name+".pdf", FileMode.Create));
        document.Open();

        iTextSharp.text.html.simpleparser.HTMLWorker hw = new iTextSharp.text.html.simpleparser.HTMLWorker(document);
        FontFactory.Register(Path.Combine(_webHelper.MapPath("~/App_Data/Pdf/arial.ttf")),  "Garamond");   // just give a path of arial.ttf 
        StyleSheet css = new StyleSheet();
        css.LoadTagStyle("body", "face", "Garamond");
        css.LoadTagStyle("body", "encoding", "Identity-H");
        css.LoadTagStyle("body", "size", "12pt");

        hw.SetStyleSheet(css);

         hw.Parse(new StringReader(htmlText));
```

Hope this helps
Regards,
Vinit Patel